# How to make django do user independent or session independent tasks?

Tags: django, session, cron

I am working on a project which periodically downloads stock details as a json file from a web server and save locally for user requestes .Since it is not appropriate to download the same for each user request i need help in doing that

I know how to do it using cron but i prefer it in django itself ..

Comment: Cron *is* the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a django command using `while True` loop and `thread.sleep(intervaltime)` function.

And after starting django server, run this `python manage.py commandname`

Comment: is while True: an efficient mechanism ?I am a beginner with 2 days of experience

Comment: Nope.Cron is the way to go.But it can do the job for you.see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/